# Create custom post type wordpress: change the labels

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-type

I have registered my custom post type, but I was wondering how I can change the labels for the "all" the one that appears immediately below the title.

For instance in the Post category I have "All Posts", for Media I can see Library ... but after I have created my custom post type, my "all" item has the same name of the main one.

This is the label array I have created.

```
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Facebook', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Facebook', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Facebook'),
    'add_new_item' => __("Add New Facebook Post"),
    'edit_item' => __("Edit Facebook Post"),
    'new_item' => __("New Facebook Post"),
    'view_item' => __("View Facebook Posts"),
    'search_items' => __("Search in Facebook Posts"),
    'not_found' =>  __('No facebook posts found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No facebook posts found in Trash'), 
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
  );
```

By changing either the name or the Singular_name both the "Header" and the "All" menu items change. I can only suspect there is a label that is missing, but I can't find any documentation on this regard.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the '`all_items'` label

```
'all_items' => 'All Facebook Posts',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/)